# updating options on signature pad plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to update the options on Signature Pad but it does not seem to be working.

The option that I am trying to update is the pen colour, i have created a button that once clicked on should update the object and change the pen colour.

```
var options = {
    drawOnly: true,
    defaultAction: 'drawIt',
    validateFields: false,
    lineWidth: 0,
    output: null,
    sigNav: null,
    name: null,
    typed: null,
    clear: 'input[type=reset]',
    typeIt: null,
    drawIt: null,
    typeItDesc: null,
    drawItDesc: null,
    penColour: '#000',
};

var api = $('form').signaturePad(options);

$('.green').click(function(){
    api.clearCanvas();
    $.fn.signaturePad.penColour = '#00FF00';
});
```

any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure using `$.fn.signaturePad.penColour` is the correct way to change the pen color? And are you sure that the value `00FF00` is in the correct format (vs `#00FF00`, for example)? Also, remove the last comma in `options`.

Comment: Also, have you verified that the `.click()` is happening when you expect it to?

Comment: This is the way it says to do it in the documentation @matthewpavkov and yes the click function is working fine as the clear canvas method works

Comment: I believe my updated answer addresses your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can supply new options when you regenerate the signature.

Documentation: http://thomasjbradley.ca/lab/signature-pad/#api

Using the API:

```
$('.green').click(function() {
    // Store the signature JSON object so you can regenerate
    var sig = api.getSignatureString();

    api.clearCanvas();

    // Regenerate the signature with the updated option
    api.updateOptions({ penColour: '#00FF00' }).regenerate(sig);
});
```

Or, you can just recreate the whole thing, without the API:

```
$('.green').click(function(){
    // This is a JSON formatted signature
    var sig = api.getSignatureString();
    api.clearCanvas();
    var options = {
        penColour: '#00FF00'
        /* other options */
    }

    $('form').signaturePad(options).regenerate(sig);
});
```

Comment: Thank you!! I used your previous example using $('form').signaturePad(options).regenerate(); and it works exactly how i need it :)